# Problem with multiple instances of VideoCapture in python cv2

Tags: python, testing, opencv

For my project I wanted to create a subclass to opencv VideoCapture, which looks like that:

```
import cv2

class VideoOperator(cv2.VideoCapture):
    def __init__(self, video_path):
        super().__init__(video_path)
        self.current_frame_index = 0
        self.last_frame_index = int(self.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - 1)

    def move_to_frame(self, frame_index):
        if frame_index > self.last_frame_index:
            self.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.last_frame_index)
            self.current_frame_index = self.last_frame_index
        elif frame_index < 0:
            self.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
            self.current_frame_index = 0
        else:
            self.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_index)
            self.current_frame_index = frame_index

    def move_x_frames(self, x):
        self.move_to_frame(self.current_frame_index + x)

    def get_current_frame(self):
        _, image = self.read()
        self.move_to_frame(self.current_frame_index)
        return image
```

Then I wrote some tests using unittest. Since I want a fresh instance of my subclass, I decided to create it in `setUp()` function. Tests (incomplete) look as follows:

```
import unittest, time
import video_operator

class TestVideoOperator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.vid_op = video_operator.VideoOperator(r'E:\PythonProjects\video_cutter\vid1.mp4')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.vid_op.release()


    def test_init(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.vid_op.current_frame_index, 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.vid_op.last_frame_index, 430653)

    def test_move_to_existing_frame(self):
        self.vid_op.move_to_frame(100)
        self.assertEqual(self.vid_op.current_frame_index, 100)

    def test_move_to_negative_frame(self):
        self.vid_op.move_to_frame(-100)
        self.assertEqual(self.vid_op.current_frame_index, 0)

    def test_move_to_non_existing_frame(self):
        self.vid_op.move_to_frame(self.vid_op.last_frame_index + 100)
        self.assertEqual(self.vid_op.current_frame_index, self.vid_op.last_frame_index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But even though there are 4 tests, only 1 is executed and it always end with information about some exit code like that:

[image]

When I just define vid_op as class field and not try to initialize it at the beginning of each test, everything works perfectly. Is it impossible to create multiple instances of VideoCapture class even though I release each before creating another? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving enough time to VideoCapture to initialize?
I'm using cv2 to read 16 RTSP cameras in parallel. It takes almost/over 1 minute to initialize.
In my case, I cannot use VideoCapture.read() because it's too much work to process. I'm disposing some frames and grabbing just a few by running cap.grab() in a high speed loop and the frames I intend to show I use cap.retrieve() this way I only decode the ones of my interest and increase the app performance. eg. to show a camera in a 3FPS basis for a 30FPS camera, you should take 1 frame at 10 frames interval.
Another point to mention is that, Linux has demonstrated to handle these VideoCapture objects a lot better than Windows 10 does.
Even a Raspberry pi can run multiple VideoCaptures in parallel after a few minutes of initialization.
Hope this information helps.